# Run command in the browser's console during the test in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I would like to include this command during the test in TestCafe. I found that I can execute JavaScript code using client-functions and t.eval but I have no idea how to proceed with this.

Command that need to be executed automatically during the test:

document.querySelector(".Watchlist--form").submit()

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is impossible to use [test actions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/) to submit your form, you will need to create a [Client Function](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#creating-client-functions) to do it:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const submitAction = ClientFunction(() => {
    document.querySelector(".Watchlist--form").submit();
});

fixture `My fixture`
    .page `http://example.com`;

test('My test', async t => {
    // Some actions and assertions before the submit action
    await t
        .click(Selector(...))
        ...
        .expect(...).ok();

    // Submit action
    await submitAction();

    // Some actions and assertions after the submit action
    await t
        .click(Selector(...))
        ...
        .expect(...).ok();
});
```

Comment: I am happy to hear that this test code was helpful. May I ask you to mark our answer as a "solution" to make it more discoverable for other users?